# when does a dynamically loaded CSS into head get executed

Tags: javascript, php, css

If already answered somewhere, I would appreciate the link I just can't find it.

I load .php pages with either 
`<?php include 'header.php'; ?>` directly or on button/link action with

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" role="button" data-target="#genericModal" onclick="loadModalContent(\'profil.php\',\'genericModal\')">.
```

Some of the loaded children need the same .css & other files as their parent, so I though I would use the following code to load

```
function loadStyleSheet(uri){
    //jquery might not be loaded yet, so do long form
    var ss = document.styleSheets;
    for (var i = 0, max = ss.length; i < max; i++) {
        if (ss[i].href.indexOf(uri) > -1){
            return;
        }
    }
    var styleSheet = document.createElement("link");
    styleSheet.href = uri;
    styleSheet.rel = "stylesheet";
    styleSheet.type = "text/css";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleSheet);
};
```

and then I have i.e. two files:

parent.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <link....something else and more....
    </head>
    <body>
        load in one way or another the child.php
    </body>
</html>
```

and

child.php (no html, no head or body)

```
<script>
    loadStyleSheet("css/bootstrap.css");
    loadStyleSheet("css/child.css");
</script>
<div class="xyz">
    something more here
</div>
```

But my question is now, how the browsers react to it. Because basically the parent already went through his `<head></head>` and is building the page and somewhere in the middle I tell him to load some other code and oh by the way, append a .css with javascript to his `<head>` (I don't have `<head>`s in the child files). How do browsers react to this?

I understand I probably could use loaders, but would like to avoid them for now.

I also could add all children .css into the parents, but for clarity and load on demand design would like to keep them in the children .phps

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The browser should respond to DOM changes - which would include adding a stylesheet - right away.

However, "right away" is limited because the browser runs things single-threaded, and because it needs to actually load the stylesheet (probably from a remote location).

**Generally** a re-render will occur when any script that modified the DOM ends.  (That could mean essentially at the `</script>` tag for an inline script, or when the event handler returns if an event triggered the script...)

So if you were to step through with a debugger, you would see that the `<link>` element appears under head as soon as you execute the following line:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleSheet);
```

But the page won't have re-rendered yet.

**But even when the DOM is re-rendered** if the new stylesheet resource hasn't had time to load then the rendered page will not appear updated.  To a user, it will appear that the stylesheet is applied at some unspecified time, no sooner than completion of the script that created the `<link>` element.

Comment: The page is actually re-rendered some time after the script ends, since the stylesheet will take time to download. This will make a visible difference for slow internet connections, or large stylesheets.

Comment: True; was thinking of resources as local, which of course is silly.  What I wrote would be closer to true if the script constructed a <style> tag directly to take loading out of the equation - but that doesn't make a lot of sense.  Updating with a more realistic answer...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to have all the css your parent and child need added at first. If you need clarity, you can split it in two files and add them both.

But if you can't perhaps you could load the style rules inside a `<style>` tag instead of a `<link>`

Of course if you put the css inside a `<style>` you're not taking advantage of the caching of the browser, but if you're worried about not using it, why not to load all the css in the first place

take a look at [this](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Dynamic_style_-_manipulating_CSS_with_JavaScript) site

Comment: adding them at first, means, if I have multiple parents, I always must ensure I know exactly which children might be potentially loaded, which I don't really want to keep track of. How does style vs link help me. Do you mean I should put CSS code in the php directly. I really don

Comment: don't want to do that, as I am reusing files. Is there anything specific, you had in mind that I should look at at the proposed page. It seem to me it is just standard handling of CSS with javascript, which I am actually already using in my code above.

Comment: or did you mean with style instead of link to append element style. If so, my question is still, when/how does that element get (loaded) parsed.

Comment: I was thinking, instead of loading the child css as a new asset (in your loadstyles function, you're creating a link element and append it inside the head) I would load the stylesheet but pass it as the content of a `<style>` and append it to the `<body>`

Comment: Now I'm thinking... you have multiple parents and children. How is your CSS structured? perhaps you could set your markups in the same hierarchy and so you could pull all the css and only the adequate style gets applied.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it's a proof of concept that might work for your desired application.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" media="none" onload="$_font_awesome_media = this; console.log($_font_awesome_media.media); $_font_awesome_media.media='all'" />

<button type="submit" onclick="$_font_awesome_media.media='none'">Send Emails</button>
```

The button will manipulate the media query to turn off the font-awesome.css file. You can use this technique to show the .css files you want to show inside your child modules.

Simply use the following javascript to enable it.

```
$_font_awesome_media.media='all'
```

Please take into consideration that this is probably a "hack" but, it gets the job done and in a very efficient manner. The css files will be downloaded in the background so it doesn't slow down the website from loading initially. If Javascript is disabled you will need to determine how to handle that separately.